# WP get stuck with a query on MySQL when the site is resumed

Tags: database

I'm running my web site from a local dev on a VM. Everything works fine with the exception of the resuming bit.

When I resume the machine, systematically WP takes ages to load. And actually the problem is not with WP itself but with MySQl and a query WP is doing against the DB.

Looking into what query / process the system is hang on using the following command

```
mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD DATABASE -e "show processlist;"
```

Return the following

```
| 203 | jumpinuk | localhost:60327 | jumpinuk | Query   |    0 | closing tables | INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('_transient_doing_cron' |
```

The above can stay there until I don't brutally stop the service and restart it. And even while restarting MySQL can take a little while to complete the procedure.
Doeas anybody experencied the same?

Is there any chance to figure out what is the plugin (if any) or the part of the site that want to interact with my Cron? I don't have anything AFAIK.

Thanks?

Comment: One way to find out is to disable all the plugins one at a time and reboot the VM!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an issue similar to this with two separate machines (db and web).  Calls from web server to the db server were taking an extraordinary amount of time and it turned out to be that MySQL was trying to do IP resolution on each call to it, causing a DNS lookup.   Because the db server was internal and had no connection to the outside world, the lookup would eventually timeout.

I resolved the problem by adding the skip-name-resolve directive in the my.conf file on the db server.

Comment: That's perfect my friend. I did try to change the database address from localhost to 127.0.0.1 without success in the hope to stop the name resolution all the time, but apparently it didn't work. This one had.